# make getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) work on andorid 2.2 or higher not just android 3.0 or higher

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am working with android actionbars in my app i have implemented the action bar successfully but it works only on 3.0 or higher

the documentation says actionbar was introduced in android honeycomb which had the api version 11 , my code works when i have android:minSdkVersion 11 , i want to **make it work on android 2.2 or higher**
i.e android:minSdkVersion="8"

i have included the **import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar**; however even then it doesnot work properly

**i dont want to use actionbarsherlock**

i want to use getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true),

i have even tried using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); it also doesnot work this is my code gives me error message The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Activity

```
package com.Blog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

import com.Blog.image.ImageLoader;
import com.Blog.parser.RSSFeed;

public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    RSSFeed feed;
    ListView lv;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    String feedLink;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;

    private  String[] planets;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;
    //private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.feed_list);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                //Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Drawer closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                //Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Drawer opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);



        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
        planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(ListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets ));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // set the feed link for refresh
        //feedLink = new SplashActivity().RSSFEEDURL;
        //feedLink = new SplashActivity().RSSFEEDURL;

        // Get feed form the file
        feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");

        // Initialize the variables:
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set an Adapter to the ListView
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set on item click listener to the ListView
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // actions to be performed when a list item clicked
                int pos = arg2;

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,
                        DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        Intent intent = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.action_share:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello!");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.menuSortNewest:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, aSearch.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

            break;

        case R.id.menuSortRating:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, CSearch.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);





        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // List adapter class
    class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        public CustomListAdapter(ListActivity activity) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            // Set the total list item count
            return feed.getItemCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Inflate the item layout and set the views
            View listItem = convertView;
            int pos = position;
            if (listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            // Initialize the views in the layout
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView tvDate = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.date);

            // Set the views in the layout
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(feed.getItem(pos).getImage(), iv);
            tvTitle.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getTitle());
            tvDate.setText(feed.getItem(pos).getDate());

            return listItem;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Drawer closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, bListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, aListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ccategoryListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, dListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 4) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, eActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 5) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivityQ.class);
            intent.putExtra("country", "Exam");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 6) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivityQ1.class);
            intent.putExtra("country", "Quiz");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (position == 7) {
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (position == 8) {
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (position == 9) {
            String webpage = "http://developer.android.com/index.html";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webpage));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    }
}
```

android mainfest

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<activity
            android:name="com.Blog.ListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

styles.xml

```
</style>
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Use `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: if you read my question i have mentioned i have tried using `getSupportActionBar()` it also gives me error message The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type Activity

Comment: Sorry, my Bad you should extend it with `actionbaractivity`

Comment: i have another activity which uses public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener{ how can i use it with fragmentActivity

Comment: treid using actionbaractivity app crashes after that